# Ember Router does not initialize (w/ ember-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm having trouble getting my application to load start via the router. I am using the ember-rails gem to generate assets. I created one resource and I am trying to connect it through the ember router, but the router never routes anything.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/) is a link to a JSFiddle of the code generated by ember-rails. The only code I added myself is the `enter`, `connectOutlets`, and the `location` attribute on the router creation.

What am I missing?

Comment: That's an empty link. And if you are using 0.9.8 in your code, beware it has a very immature Router implementation.

Comment: Did you call App.initialize() ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure how that is an empty link, it worked when I wrote the post. Would it be best to use the master branch then? (1.0.0.pre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a really good, basic ember-rails example on github [here](https://github.com/bazzel/ember-sample2). In this example he uses a more up to date version of ember that seems to solve my problems.